# Properly defining and plotting a function that requires `NSolve`

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, variable-definitions, error-propagation

I want to defined a function that solves some equation numerically:

```
h[r_, R_, l_, n_] := NSolve[l^2 == r^2 + R^2 - 2 h^2 - 2 Sqrt[(r^2 - h^2) (R^2 - h^2)] Cos[2 Pi/n] && h >= 0, h, Reals]
```

I then want to plot this function via

```
DensityPlot[h[r,1,l,6], {r,0,1}, {l,0,1}]
```

Of course, this does not work, as `NSolve` does not return a numeric value, but a list of lists of rules, which might even be empty.

My intention would be to define `h` in such a way, so that it extracts the desired numerical value (the unique positive solution, if there is one), and otherwise returns, ..., well, no idea actually. What should it return otherwise? What I want in the end, is that `DensityPlot` works well with that function, so that regions where `h` is not well-defined are just blank. The region where it is not well-defined are not explicitly known, though.

I thought about defining `h` so that it returns `Indeterminate` whenever the list is empty, but then `DensityPlot` seems to throw $Failure. Also

```
RegionPlot[h[r,1,l,6] =!= Indeterminate, {r,0,1}, {l,0,1}]
```

does not to work for showing the region in which `h` is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Try `?NumericQ` and assign  the NSolve result to `h`

```
h[r_?NumericQ, R_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ, n_?NumericQ] :=h /. NSolve[
l^2 == r^2 + R^2 - 2 h^2 -2 Sqrt[(r^2 - h^2) (R^2 - h^2)] Cos[2 Pi/n] && h >= 0, h,Reals][[1]]
DensityPlot[h[r, 1, l, 4], {r, 0, 1}, {l, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this also work for `h[r,1,l,6]`? I will edit the question, as the case with `4` wasn't actually the problematic one. Sorry for this! But in general, how does `?NumericQ` solve the issue?

Comment: I tested it, and it cannot handle the case `h[r,1,l,6]`, as then the `NSolve` might find no solutions, and `[[1]]` fails.

Comment: Try `ContourPlot3D[
 l^2 == 0.0025 - 2 h^2 + r^2 - Sqrt[(0.0025 - h^2) (-h^2 + r^2)], {r, 
  0, 1}, {l, 0, 1}, {h, 0, 0.05}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]` to check the possible solutions !